# Split a array into multiple array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

if i need to split array in to specific length as example let say i have array with 16 elements and i wanna split this in to 3 arrays and each array include 5 elements 
when it comes to last array should take rest of them 
so output should be something like this

- array 1 with 5 elements
- array 2 with 5 elements
- array 3 with 6 elements

i really like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37071103/301502) but it cannot split in to predefined length

```
public static IEnumerable<List<int>> SplitWhenNotIncreasing(List<int> numbers)
{
    for (int i = 1, start = 0; i <= numbers.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (i != numbers.Count && numbers[i] > numbers[i - 1])
            continue;

        yield return numbers.GetRange(start, i - start);
        start = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the final array were just the left overs it would be easy.

Comment: What if your array contains less than 3 elements? What if it contains 10 elements? how about 60? and 28? What's the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> SplitArray<T>(T[] arr, int splitsNumber)
{
    var list = arr.ToList();
    int size = list.Count / splitsNumber;
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i + 1 < splitsNumber; ++i, pos += size)
    {
        yield return list.GetRange(pos, size);
    }

    yield return list.GetRange(pos, list.Count - pos);
}
```